# pass multiple variable through javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have used the following code to delete a specific record. It works perfectly

```
<script>
function deleteRecord(x) {
  if(confirm("You want to delete  ?")) {
    window.location.href='delete1iud.php?Stu_id='+x;
  }
}
</script>
<a href='#' onclick='deleteRecord(".$id.")'>Delete</a>

/* ------------------- */
$x=$_REQUEST['Stu_id'];
```

Now I need to pass another php variable `$table` through it. I have tried the following code. But this time it's not working.

```
function deleteRecord(x, tab)  {
  window.location.href='delete1iud.php?Stu_id='+x +'&t='tab;    
}

<a href='#' onclick='deleteRecord(".$id.", ".$table.")'>Delete</a>

/* ------------------- */
$x=$_REQUEST['Stu_id'];
$table=$_REQUEST['t'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`'&t='tab` should be `'&t=' + tab`

Comment: So this question should be closed as off-topic typo then?  Because clearly the OP knows how to concatenate string as demoed in the first snippet.

Comment: made the suggested change. But that too not working

Comment: Is table an array?

Comment: No, just a string . $table='a334';

Comment: it should pass '.a334.' then. You're defining $table in both this php file and delete1iud.php right?

Comment: Yes. My aim is to set $table='a334' in delete1iud.php. I can not directly use it because the name a334 is supplied as a parameter of a function in the original file.